# Use PanGestureRecognizer translationInView to track touch location

Tags: uiview, translation, rotation, cgaffinetransform

How would i use a PanGestureRecognizer's `translationInView` which returns a `CGPoint`, to track the user touch location so that i can rotate an image so that the point where the user touches stays under the finger?

I can use `CGAffineTransformRotate` to do the rotation but it expects a rotation angle in radians. Currently i am using `M_PI/20;`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your code:

```
#define degreesToRadians(degrees) (M_PI * degrees / 180.0)
#define radiansToDegrees(radians) (radians * 180 / M_PI)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides these [GLKit functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKMathUtils/index.html) for conversion:

```
func GLKMathDegreesToRadians(_ degrees: Float) -> Float
func GLKMathRadiansToDegrees(_ radians: Float) -> Float
```